# Border radius property breaks on table footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a table with rounded corners with both a header and a footer with different colors than the main table. Ideally, the header and footer would both inherit from the parent table, but being able to separately round the footer/header would be fine for my purposes.

The current issue is highlighted here: http://jsfiddle.net/VfVx9/

```
tfoot{
    background: #ff0000;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

In my mind directly giving the footer a border radius should round the corners, but that doesn't quite seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Note - `The effect of border-radius on internal table elements is undefined in CSS3 Backgrounds and Borders, but may be defined in a future specification.` - http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-css3-background-20080910/#border-radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/JLyrp/

```
.test {
    background: #0000ff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
tfoot {
    background: #ff0000;
    border-radius:20px;
    display:block  //float or position:absolute also works
}
```

Comment: Oh woah, that's bizarre. Do you know why display:block does that? Also is there any way to have it actually display as a footer? That example moved it pretty far from the bottom of the table and that's less than ideal.

Comment: The fiddle has a table row below the footer. If the tfoot is actually at the bottom, it will sit at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this:

```
<div id="table">

<div class="head">
    Table head
</div>

<div class="tablerow">
    Table row content
</div>

<div class="tablerow">
    Table row content
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Table footer
</div>
```

and then:

```
#table {
background-color: blue;
width:200px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#table div {
padding: 5px;  
}

#table .head {
background-color: green;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#table .footer {
background-color: red;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VfVx9/

Comment: Not only does that still have the issue I was trying to fix, but the fiddle was just an example. I'm actually using this with dynamic content.

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa... I put in the wrong link. http://jsfiddle.net/VfVx9/2/ Here that actually works. I'm sorry. @SlaterTyranus

Comment: Just take a look at it please.

Comment: Oh! That's so much better!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this depends on which browser you are using, try this:

```
tfoot{
  background: #ff0000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but no change.

Comment: I had the same problem and it worked for me, then maybe you are using a very old browser?

Comment: Nah, using Chrome 28, also tested in FF. Did you try editing the fiddle I put up?